# Running an executable on memory

Tags: python, executable

I would like to write an encrypted file (I already have an encryption tool).

The encryption tool can work only on a file.

My python code does the following:

1. Get necessary inputs from user (cmd prompt)
2. Perform some mathematical operations
3. Writeout a temporary un-encrypted file on hard disk.
4. Run the encryption executable on the file written out in previous step.
5. Delete the temporary file (from step 3) after the encrypted file is generated in step 4.

Problem is that, the file written out in step 3 can be easily found if somebody is really looking for it. Is there a way to run the encryption tool (bat file) without writing the file on hard disk?

I already tried running the script on hidden files and it does not help at all.

Comment: Why do you necessarily want to write a temporary file? What's wrong with keeping the content in a `string` or a `bytearray`? It's not unhackable but it will be more difficult to find the content from the RAM instead of the hard disk

Comment: the executable on step 4 needs a file as input. So, a temporary file is needed. Wondering if there is a way to make a file in "memory" and run executable on it... Seems funny to ask but if there is a way...

Comment: What kind of encryption tool do you use ? I think that the answer is more on its side rather than python-side

Comment: It is a third party tool. Dont have much information on it but can only run it with cmd prompt.
Yes, I started believing that the tool needs a change and nothing much can be on my script.

Comment: Maybe simply create a new user which will run the python script, and play with the permissions so that your temporary file cannot be read by others.

Comment: You can use `tmpfs` on a linux system to create a temporary RAM disk. Still the data will be visible while your file is there. With that and playing with user permissions, you might have a solution